# Add eslinitng rules to existing JS quality profile

Tags: sonarqube

I want to add a set of es linting to the existing JS profile in SonarQube, I couldn't find an option to do that. I don't want to manually enter them as I have many rules.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to copy the quality profile from one SonarQube instance to another?

Comment: I am trying to add some javascript eslinting rules to the exsisting js profile @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: So can you please edit your question so that it is clearer on this topic please?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Edited, is there a answer for it?

Comment: Can you be more precise? When you say "es linting", are you talking about rules from the existing ESLint engine? (http://eslint.org/)

Comment: Yes, from the exisitng ES linting engine to Sonar Way JS profile because i couldn't find any  ES linting plugin avaliable in SOnar qube

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube JavaScript plugin does not support external rule engines like ESLint,JSLint, JSHint or JSCS. So you can't import rule definitions from those engines.

For your information, you can come and discuss on the [SonarQube Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) so that the SonarQube JavaScript team can hear your needs in terms of rules.